# Ajax is eluding me. How to execute a simple ajax request?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

Okay background i am a js and ajax noob. I work mainly in php and mysql html 5, i decided to get with the times and stop having to reload the page for simple things.

I am trying to make a simple ajax request to a php file and print the result.

So on my page i have a text bax with the id password(leftover from another experiment)
a jquery ui tabs setup with a tab with the id galleries and a div with the id my-galleries. The idea is that upon click on the galleries tab the value of the password field is pulled and sent to the php file my-galleries.php and the result is printed to the div my-galleries and displayed.

The code:

```
<input type="password" id="password"/>    
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li id="welcome"><a href="content/welcome.html">Welcome</a></li>
        <li><a href="content/about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#my-galleries" id="galleries">Galleries</a></li>
        <li><a href="content/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="my-galleries"></div>
</div>
```

Then the js

```
$("#galleries").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'my-galleries.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {
            password : $('#password').val()
        },
        success: function(msg){
            $("#my-galleries").html(msg)
        }           
    })
});
```

Then the php

```
$password= $_REQUEST['password'];
$salt= uniqid();
$str= $salt.$password;
$hash= hash("sha512", $str);
echo $hash;
```

According to the tuts i have been reading it should work but it doesn't. I cant figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried using FireBug in the FireFox browser to see any Javascript errors?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Do you get javascript errors?  Does the code get to your ajax success handler?  If so, what is the value of `msg` there?  Are you getting an ajax error?  Did you create an error handling function and see whether it's getting called with error info?  Did you look at the network trace in the javascript debugger and see what is actually being sent over the network?  These are all standard debugging methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're requesting JSON; your data is definitely not JSON. It's plain text, so use the `'text'` `dataType`:

```
$("#galleries").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'my-galleries.php',
        dataType: 'jsontext',
        data: {
            password : $('#password').val()
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#my-galleries").html(msg)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is indeed the problem, but there may be more of them, eg. `$('#galleries')` may not find anything, if not used correctly (see my answer). But without changing `dataType` (or removing it), it would not work anyway ;)

Comment: @SpeedCrazy: Good :) Then accept his answer and give a lot more details next time within your question :)

Comment: @SpeedCrazy: If this is the answer, you should mark it as such (click the green check under the `^ 4 v`) for future visitors.

Comment: I told you i was a noob i did not know what info to give. If you had asked i would have answered. And thanks i did not know about the accept feature.

Comment: @SpeedCrazy: I did not have to ask you - I told you what to do in most of the cases I mentioned, there were multiple possibilities :) jfriend00 asked similar questions in the comments, but has not been answered, I believe. Anyway problem solved, minitech identified it correctly and fixed it, no other problems are known :) Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Use debugging tools from your browser, eg. Firebug in Firefox or Developer Tools in Google Chrome / Chromium.

This will show you possible problems. They may be the following:

1. There is an error in your JavaScript.
2. You may be asking wrong destination.
3. There may be a redirection after request.
4. There may be an error on the server (resulting in `success()` callback not being executed). Check the response using debugging tools.
5. The data type may not be what you have specified. Check if it is JSON.
6. `$` may not be defined. Check if it is.
7. Your JS may be executed before the DOM objects (specifically the one with "`galleries`" ID) are available. Put your code eg. in `$(function(){/* your code here */});`.
8. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
echo $hash;
```

to

```
echo json_encode(array('response' => $hash));
```

then access it like so in your success block:

```
$("#my-galleries").html(msg.response);
```

assuming you really want json for some reason. Otherwise definitely use [minitech's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8736710/707111).

...also, just my opinion, you should `die($hash);` and not `echo $hash;`: kill the script on response.

Comment: Why kill the script on response?

Comment: standard practice at the firm I work for. We're not in the habit of having ajax handlers run beyond specific methods, but should you happen to have this in a conditional with non conditional things below it, you could echo other things not intended and get undesired effects. It of course depends on your programming style, or the style of the code you inherit if you work at a firm. Plus, it will cease evaluating the file if you are also so awful as to have a 30k line ajax handler... seen it.

Comment: @KaiQing: Bad practice, but reasonable one if you have old and unmaintainable system, which really prints something after that. In normal cases you should never do that, as it actually makes the system unmaintainable.

Comment: Wouldn't the unmaintainability of the system also depend on the coding style / standard? Like I said in my post - just my opinion.